# mmenu.jquery slide out menu is preventing adsense from displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, adsense

I just redesigned my website with a responsive design and now my google adsense ads are not showing up regularly.  It seems to be most prevalent on Apple products like my ipad, iphone and Macbook Pro.  When viewing my home page (http://www.recipegraze.com), blank spots show up instead of ads.  On my detail pages (just click on any of the photos), there should be two rectangle ads, but only one typically shows up.  Sometimes hitting refresh will make the ads show up, but then when you load a new page they are gone again.

I know this is a widespread problem on my site since earnings have plummeted since the new design went live.

The problem seems to be related to the mmenu.jquery slide-in mobile menu that I am using (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl).  If I delete the includes for the mmenu css and javascript, the ads show just fine.

So please help me find a solution. It could be either a fix to make mmenu work or some other method of doing the slide out menu.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: There is an error:
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
 

...){this.Fb||(a?this.wb=!0:this.wa=!0)};X.prototype.Pb=function(a,b){this.Ma(a);th...

show_ads_impl.js (line 89)
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal how did you get that error? I'm looking in console and I don't see that.  Thanks!

Comment: I used browser console to view the error

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem on my own site. Depending on what order the adsense is called relative to the mmenu plugin sometimes the ads do indeed appear. I'm still trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Sorry @EvanMcEwen I was not able to find a solution.  I think I'm going to redo the nav using bootstrap when I get around to it. I used the bootstrap response nav on another site and no problems like this yet.

Comment: I've attempted to make the developer aware of the issue after some minor debugging myself. Here's hoping something will come of it: https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/90

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact problem with a few other libraries that's wrecking havoc on the ads, as well.  Therefore, this is what I ended up doing to make the ads serve more reliably (Note: This is not a patch to mmenu, but this could apply to other libraries beyond mmenu):

Assumptions
1. mmenu loads synchronously when the page loads
2. DFP don't have strict timing loading requirements.

The theory is to load mmenu first before loading the ads.  That way, whatever mmenu (or any library) does internally does not interfere with the rest of the site.  This can be done in a few ways (I will mention two):

1. **Use callbacks**
   Load mmenu and use a callback when it's complete to procedurally load the ads.  In this case, we want to use the 'trigger' method to accomplish this.

`$("#mmenu").mmenu({
      // Options
      ...
    }, {
      // Configuration
      ...
    }).trigger(loadMyAds());`

2. **Use an event handler**
   In most cases, mmenu gets loaded on page load, but not after.  Therefore, it should be relatively safe to use an onLoad() event handler to set up the ads after page execution like this:

`$(document).ready(function() {
       googletag.cmd.push(function() {
         googletag.display("some-place-holder");
         googletag.pubads().refresh([some-ad-object]);
       });
    });`

Hope this helps (even though this is technically a workaround).